# embeded ever filled database in web mobile application (html5)

Tags: android, html, web-applications, mobile

i have a basic question that i am asking myself.

i want to make an application using jquery mobile and phogegap or m-project to make it working on android and iphone ...

I have ever populated data that i want to embed inside the application (to get all the data needed when downloading the application)

i know that html5 has store functionnalities (with a registry like or a sql like access)

in a nice world, i would prefer sql like to make request with string pattern search into my data ..

i am wondering how to prepopulate the data ... ?
- with a .cvs file the a javascript read then insert into the persistent sql like data base?
- maybe can i copy a raw sql like database populated into my application?

With a native application (java for android and objectivC with Iphone) i know how to do this ... (just embedded a file then reading it for searching patterns and info)...

But with a web mobile 'offline' application ... I don't have the answer if an answer exists!

Maybe can you help me ...

Thank you very much for reading this topic ...